# Get the multiples of 5 out of a list

Tags: r

Im look for a function through which I can get all the multiples of 5 in a list.
So if I have a list like this:

```
inds <- c(5,6,7,10)
```

The output should be

```
5,10
```

I try to do this using:

```
inds[which(3%%5 == 0),]
```

But this trows an error. Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: inds[inds %% 5 == 0]

Comment: the closest to what you have tried already is `inds[which(inds%%5==0)]`.

Answer (score 4):

We can do with `%%`

```
inds[!inds%%5]
#[1]  5 10
```